# getElementsByTagName title is coming back with DOMNodeList Object

Tags: php, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

Our script uses dom to parse all the a tags from a document then loops through child nodes and extracts information which works fine here's how the code starts

```
@$dom->loadHTML($str);
$documentLinks = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Part of the loop

```
$this->count]['href']     = strip_tags($documentLink->getAttribute('href'));
```

I now need to get the title tag from each page were lopping through so I thoguht I could do

```
$documentTitle = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
$documentLinks = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Then add this to the loop/array to get the document title but it comes back with "[title] => DOMNodeList Object()" How can I include the title tag in the loop which is going through a tags/child nodes?

```
$this->count]['title']  = $documentTitle;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName returns a DOMNodeList object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php). You want the text content of the first (should only be one page title) item in the list.

Try this:

```
$documentTitle = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
```